# How to send image data to server? (I already have a sample page)

Tags: iphone, html, post, file-upload, nsurlrequest

How to send image data to server? (I already have a sample page)

***Sample Page html Source Code***

```
<form action="/uploadfile.html" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return validate();">

    <fieldset><legend>Upload File</legend>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="fileData" id="image" type="file" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><br />
            </td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

It works fine on web page. (File Name: 1234.png)
This server check file name and save specific DB.

***Example*** (These work very well on web page *http://SAMPLE_PAGE.com/uploadfile.html*)

```
1234.png or 5678.png =upload=> save to number.db
abcd.png or wxyz.png =upload=> save to alphabet.db
```

I must upload via iOS and I have a data object (imgData).

```
NSData *imgData; //  Image Data
NSString *wantedFileName = @"1234.png";
```

How to upload to server via iOS Device? (like sample web-page)

Answer (score 0):

When we want to upload any file on server using some application we can use multi-part request for this. In this we create a NSURLMutableRequest object with multipart body having desired data.

You can visit following links for a pointer:
[send image to server in multipart iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659806/send-image-to-server-in-multipart-iphone)

[Sending multipart request from iPhone to Ruby on Rails (RoR) server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182847/sending-multipart-request-from-iphone-to-ruby-on-rails-ror-server)